# How to load dynamic library defined extern integer from python

Tags: python, c++, dll, extern

```
extern int acc;
void Cassie2d::Step(ControllerTorque* action)
{
  dyn_model_.setState(mj_data_->qpos, mj_data_->qvel);
  dyn_state_.UpdateDynamicState(&dyn_model_);
  mju_copy(mj_data_->ctrl, action->torques, nU);
  mj_step(mj_model_, mj_data_);
  acc = mj_data_->qacc[0];
  Render();
}
```

I use extern int here to access the variable from mj_data -> qacc, after I compiled the c++ file, how could I load this library and access the variable in python.

Comment: maybe it would be simpler to create an extern C method to change it. Python can do C function interfaces for sure.

Comment: if I use extern int acc, it would be hard to access this variable in python is that right?

Comment: okay, found a duplicate for you. Seems that it fits pretty well.

Comment: HI, it is actually not working when I use the method above

Comment: okay, can you [edit] you post to show what's not working? and how?